# How to reveal line level profiling in JS sources?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I've read [this article](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/) about analyzing runtime performance. The image below is copied from this article. If you check this image, there are yellow highlighted execution time hints for JS files next to each line in the file.

I find this line level profiling feature pretty useful and I would like to try it in my own projects, too.

However, when I open a JS source file in the sources tab, I cannot see it. Note that, I already took a performance profiling snapshot. But still I cannot see this execution time hints.

How can I reveal this feature?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I just tried it on Chrome 68 on my Mac and it was working as expected. What OS are you on? And what Chrome version? You can check at `chrome://version`.

Comment: Do you by any chance have [JavaScript samples disabled](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference#disable-js-samples)?

Comment: I am having this exact same problem too, and it is quite frustrating! I have tried resetting DevTools settings, resetting all of Chrome's settings, but nothing works. @KayceBasques, I have looked many times to see that I do not have the "Disable JavaScript Samples" box checked. A workaround is to go to 3 dots on right, more tools, JavaScript profiler. However, this was previously built into the Performance panel. I really need that to be built in to Performance for workflow reasons.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue. just upgraded to v72 and it's still not working, the per-line timings column just doesn't appear. @KayceBasques ?

Answer (score 3):

it's seems that it's removed to new tab.
you can try this:

1. open javascript profile tab (or ctrl+ shift + p on win and type javascript profile)
2. start to record the site and refresh
3. stop the record
4. click on one of the js file
   [image]
5. you got exactly what you need
   [image]

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't seeing the line by line timings from the profiler either, and it was driving me crazy for days.

My code was written in TypeScript and converted to JavaScript with source maps using esbuild.

**When I turned source maps off in esbuild, the line timings reappeared from the profiler!**

The JavaScript is close enough to the TypeScript so the line timings are still useful.

I could have sworn I'd seen it work with source maps in the past but now I'm not so sure. It would be great if the line timings did work with source maps but it kind of makes sense that they don't.

Has anyone else seen profiler line timings work on code with sourcemaps turn on?

Comment: I have some hunch I am not getting line by line timings due to source map or something also. Haven't found solution but it is a good lead. Just turning off "Enable JavaScript source maps" in the Chrome Devtools options did not seem to do it (I also have a webworker, not sure if that affects it either)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, but it starts to work when I deselect checkbox: `Disable JavaScript samples`. It works fine also with enabled Source Maps.

[image]