# How to do line-by-line performance profiling?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium

Is there any way to do this in modern Chrome?  Im not looking for 'total function time' and I dont want to add a console timer to every piece of code manually. Chrome use to have a line-by-line profiling view back around 2018 / 2020 but it doesnt seem to exist anymore.

[image: pic of old Chrome js profiling]

Have tried to find this feature in modern Chrome but cant.  Tried to download old Chrome but it wont run even when I delete my old Chrome / Chromium profile.

Comment: Please provide more details about what you are trying to do, as I didn't quite understand you.

Comment: Please click the image to see what line-by-line JS profiling use to look like in Chrome.  It shows how long in ms each command / if statement took to process by Chrome.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51775071/how-to-reveal-line-level-profiling-in-js-sources . Unless you got the image from the post I linked

Comment: No it does not but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to record `Performance` from the `Performace` tab and it will start showing.

Start recording from the performance tab and refresh the page then stop recording. Let the profiling complete. Now you can see the timer column in `Sources`.

Comment: I did that and it doesn't show the times.  Tried this multiple times, tried on multiple computers.  It seems like they removed the feature?

Comment: It works here. check this screenshot. I took it just now- http://icecream.me/21198da213253352cbc91cff9c2d5964

Comment: It does not work for me on multiple machines.  This problem has been around since 2018.  Works for some people but not others. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51775071/how-to-reveal-line-level-profiling-in-js-sources

If you look at orig screen shot it shows times for each command and not JUST functions.  Knowing the function time less useful than knowing the 'per command' run time, as shown in the main screen shot which comes from Google Chrome web site.

Also seen in this video around 4:17 mark.

https://youtu.be/oewDaISQpw0?t=256

I download old Chrome but no joy.

Comment: My screen shot shows a few things.  1) Dev console has been changed to split view so I can take screen shot.  2) Performance panel is on bottom and it has been run.  3) Source tab on top shows no times anywhere even when I scroll all the way down.  4) This is the code Performance > Bottom Up says took the most time to run.  5)  'Disable javascript samples' is not checked. 6) The very top is main function & surely ran.  But no code all the way down shows any times.

https://imgur.com/a/UqLbkJZ

Comment: Here is a profile ran on a different site and I pick the function/code Performance tab (bottom) said had the longest run time.  Sources tab (top) shows no times.

https://imgur.com/a/egsnyB4

Comment: @J.Doe That's strange. Could be because of OS, but it works for me. I recorded same page as yours. See, it shows the time - http://icecream.me/9e36a59eead6d891877de472b3b21d0d

Comment: Ive tried in Windows, Linux and MacOS.  I've tried on Chrome, Chrome Beta, Chromium and old versions of Chrome.  Your image shows FUNCTION run time.  My image shows execution time of *almost all lines* , not just 'per function'.  Seeing the overall function time is not useful.  The question is 'how to do line-by-line' profiling.  Which is what Chrome use to do.

Comment: Again, this youtube video shows the same thing - run times for many lines, not just functions.  https://youtu.be/oewDaISQpw0?t=253  Run times for for loops, array.push, etc.

Comment: I have run into exactly the same problem. I don't see any times for the individual lines either (using Chrome on Windows 11): https://imgur.com/a/dJoO62q